# Russian Peasant Multiplication

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, multiplication

Here is my short implementation of [Russian Peasant Multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication). How can it be improved?

*Restrictions* : only works when a>0,b>0

```
for(p=0;p+=(a&1)*b,a!=1;a>>=1,b<<=1);
```

Comment: I like optimal code so I'll give you an upvote, but you should have admitted in the above comments that your pre-edited post didn't have the initialization.

Comment: @Lance yes,you are right,I will modify this

Comment: My upvote because short onliner indentation MAY be poor. Though, it'd be very pleasant to read nice, indented code.

Comment: spx looks like people hate you.  im not sure why

Comment: yes, people hate me, only hate all around. I don't know why, maybe you have an answer ?

compact code produces hate, I cannot say it was didactical/instructive in any conceivable way. the intent obvious intent was vanity(burn in hell I will). this may be a possible explanation for the hate that you mention.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It can be improved by adding whitespace, proper indentation, and a proper function body:

```
int peasant_mult (int a, int b) {
  for (p = 0;
       p += (a & 1) * b, a != 1;
       a /= 2, b *= 2);
  return p;}
```

See? Now it's clear how the three parts of the `for` declaration are used.  Remember, programs are written mainly for human eyes.  Unreadable code is always bad code.

And now, for my personal amusement, a tail recursive version:

```
(defun peasant-mult (a b &optional (sum 0))
  "returns the product of a and b,
   achieved by peasant multiplication."
  (if (= a 1)
      (+ b sum)
      (peasant-mult (floor (/ a 2))
                    (* b 2)
                    (+ sum (* b (logand a 1))))))
```

Answer (score 20):

I think it's terrible
This is exactly the same code from the compiler's point of view, and (hopefully) a lot clearer

```
int sum = 0;
while(1)
{
    sum += (a & 1) * b;
    if(a == 1)
       break;

    a = a / 2;
    b = b * 2;
}
```

And now I've written it out, I understand it.

Comment: yes,that was my first implementation :) then I remembered some tricks :)

Comment: I hope I never have to write code with you, ever.
I can't see why anyone would take something like the above and produce what you have, unless they were making a half-arsed attempt at an Obfuscated C contest entry. :|

Comment: Rob, it's obvious in hindsight, but I actually thought you were talking to me to start with, not spx2!

Comment: I would think that bit shifting would be faster than division or multiplication, and I'm not sure if all compilers would do it that way. (Though they might, not sure here).

Comment: bit shifting IS faster than multiplication or division BUT any decent compiler will optimise a multiplication by a constant into a set of bitshifts if at all possible. The only compiler I ran into that didn't is an IAR H8 compiler. I suspect that's not the target platform here.

Comment: Hey, while you're at it, why didn't you replace `a & 1` with `a % 2`? And why not also replace `sum += ...` with `sum = sum + ...` too?  I mean, just to make it REALLY terrible.  Hey, if one doesn't know how to read C, one should go look for a VB job. ;)

Comment: Vlad - I can read English too, but thatdoesn'tmeanIprefertoreaditlikethis.

Answer (score 14):

There is an really easy way to improve this:

```
p = a * b;
```

It has even the advantage that a or b could be less than 0.

If you look how it really works, you will see, that it is just the normal manual multiplication performed binary. You computer does it internaly this way (1), so the easiest way to use the russian peasant method is to use the builtin multiplication.

(1) Maybe it has a more sophasticated algorithm, but in principle you can say, it works with this algorithm

Answer (score 7):

There is still a multiplication in the loop. If you wanted to reduce the cost of the multiplications, you could use this instead:

```
for(p=0;p+=(-(a&1))&b,a!=1;a>>=1,b<<=1);
```

Comment: yes,that is true my friend,fantastic !
thank you :)
but the restriction b>0 has saved you here,were it not for that
you would've been wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I don't find it particularly terrible, obfuscated or unreadable, as others put it, and I don't understand all those downvotes. This said, here is how I would "improve" it:

```
// Russian Peasant Multiplication ( p <- a*b, only works when a>0, b>0 )
// See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication
for( p=0; p+=(a&1)*b, a!=1; a>>=1,b<<=1 );
```

Answer (score 4):

`p` is not initialised.

What happens if `a` is zero?

What happens if `a` is negative?

**Update:** I see that you have updated the question to address the above problems. While your code now appears to work as stated (except for the overflow problem), it's still less readable than it should be.

Comment: p is to be initialized with 0
multiplication here works just for a>0,b>0 :)
thanks for asking

Answer (score 4):

This is for a code obfuscation contest? I think you can do better. Use misleading variable names instead of meaningless ones, for starters.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's incomplete, and very hard to read. What specific sort of feedback were you looking for?

Comment: a,b are the numbers,after the for loop p will be their product.
there,it's not hard to read.

Comment: it is harder to read than it needs to be, and the person who wrote it is not the person to judge whether it is hard to read. 

What's wrong with adding a few linebreaks?

Comment: adding linebreaks breaks compactness :)

Comment: you mean "adding linebreaks breaks unreadability". Doesn't change the compiled size.

Comment: Why don't you just write in assembly and stop screwing around with these play languages like C.  You're obviously an outstanding programmer and you should probably go into teaching or consulting.

Answer (score 3):

```
int RussianPeasant(int a, int b)
{
    // sum = a * b
    int sum = 0;
    while (a != 0)
    {
        if ((a & 1) != 0)
            sum += b;
        b <<= 1;
        a >>= 1;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer with no multiplication or division:

```
function RPM(int a, int b){
    int rtn;
    for(rtn=0;rtn+=(a&1)*b,a!=1;a>>=1,b<<=1);
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: err... (a&1)*b **IS** a multiplication. :)