# Tricky for Loop

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

I am bothered by a question of for loop in C language.

when i write:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i = 0;
    for( ; i ; )
    {
        printf("In for Loop");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Output: NOTHING PRINT.

Code get executed, but printf statement didn't print due to condition. OK, No problem here.

But when i write this code:

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    for( ; 0 ; )
    {
        printf("In for Loop");
    }
    getch();
}
```

Output: In for Loop.

My for loop get executed 1 time, but actually it must not to be executed. I don't know why? can coder/programmer/hacker of stackoverflow help me. explain me please why my for loop giving this output only one time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior. Compile without flag with g++.

Comment: nothing is printed in the second loop for me. Used Apple LLVM 3.1

Comment: How are you compiling your program? Also: Would be nice if you pasted the *entire* second version of the program, exactly as it is, instead of just the loop.

Comment: can't reproduce the problem on gcc and clang on linux.

Comment: I am compiling my program in turbo C++.

Comment: ok ArjunShankar. for you i am editing my code.

Comment: TurboC++? you should not use that, that's a arcane and out of date compiler. lot of standards came after the those borland compilers.

Comment: But this is a basic code aftnix. i need exact answer. if you had any better compiler they please compile my program and then give my answer. i am waiting for your reply.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi - The code you pasted is not standard C. There is no such thing as `conio.h` in the C standard. It's a non-standard include part of Borland/Turbo and maybe some other old old compilers. Anyway, [here is the same program and its output](http://ideone.com/Mi4Q0) (after being compiled with GCC). You will see that there is no output. The website I linked to (ideone.com) allows you to write small programs and compile and run them online.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi If the executable compiled by TurboC++ from the second code prints anything, TurboC++ is broken worse than anybody imagined.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086759/need-help-understanding-this-for-loop-code-in-c

Comment: **@Visitors from the future:** While this question has been closed as 'too localized', you really should look at @tinman's comment. This is a bug in Turbo C++. A comment on that linked question refers to the *exact same problem* as reported here. The real answer: Stop using Turbo C++ and other ancient/broken stuff.

Comment: Also: I think these down votes are unfair. At worst, this is a slightly-difficult-to-spot duplicate.

Comment: i think you are probably right. I should not use turbo c++.

Answer (score 12):

What you wrote shouldn't print anything, but I suspect the *actual* second-case code (not what you typed in) that causes the problem is:

```
for( ; 0 ; );     // <==== note the trailing semicolon there.
{
    printf("In for Loop");
}
```

In this case the for loop doesn't execute the empty statement, and then the `{ }` code is executed once.

EDIT: If this isn't the problem please just paste a complete program that exhibits the problem directly into your question.

EDIT2:

The following minimal compilable example doesn't print anything:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    for( ; 0 ; )
    {
        std::printf("In for Loop");
    }
}
```

Comment: Every programmer runs in this problem at least once in its lifetime

Comment: Yeah. I'd bet money on this one, not just because it would have the behaviour described, but also as @akappa says, everyone's done it at least once. (And if you find cases where empty `for` loops are useful, you'll do the opposite at least once too).

Comment: When I need an empty `for` loop I *still* use braces and a big fat comment saying that it's a null loop body.

Comment: No Mark B brother. i didn't write code as you typed. i don't make any silly mistakes in coding. I run this code on different systems many times. all they give me same answer. you can run my code on your c compiler. you will get the same result. I didn't add any semicolon after printf statement. reply Mark B brother, i need your help.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi You don't make any silly mistakes in coding? You'd be the only one in the whole world.

Comment: +1 for @DanielFischer's comment :D

Comment: Excellent psychic debugging, @MarkB! If you aren't "making silly mistakes coding" you probably aren't coding much.

Comment: [Link to runnable code example](http://codepad.org/9WLH6H5A)

Comment: @MarkB I am, of course, dumb and have deleted my incorrect comment :)

Comment: Funny @Mr Daniel Fscher. i like your comment. ha ha ha.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi It's not funny. _Everybody_ makes silly mistakes sometimes. If you believe you don't, you're likely to overlook more than if you are aware that you sometimes do. The first rule of programming, "if things aren't doing what you expected, it's probably your own fault".

Comment: I just mean that, i didn't make any silly mistakes in this type of short programs. for big problems, all programmer does silly mistakes.

Comment: Personally, I find I'm more likely to have a mistake in a 10 line program than in any given 100 lines of a real program. Still, we're all able to compile `for(;0;)` loops that skip the loop body.

Comment: Once compile this program in Turbo C++ buddy. The answer is surely surprising for you.

Answer (score 1):

Both ways should output nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this behavior on my machine, compiling with gcc. The two programs were:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  for( ; 0 ; )
  {
    std::cout << "Here I am!";
  }
  std::cout << "End of the program.";
}
```

outputs

```
End of Program
```

as does

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  int i = 0;
  for( ; i ; )
  {
    std::cout << "Here I am!";
  }
  std::cout << "End of Program";
}
```

This is what we would expect to happen, as the 0 read as the loop continuation condition is evaluated to false, so the loop is never entered.

Comment: But really believe me. my turbo c++ 3.0 gives me my output. your gcc may give correct answer as expected.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi Damn, that's a really old compiler. Does it run on coal?

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi It's a bug in TurboC++-3.0. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086759/need-help-understanding-this-for-loop-code-in-c) You should choose a better compiler.