# Why for loop does not run by other than int variables?

Tags: c, for-loop

Why for loop does not run by other than int variables? I tried to run for loop by taking float variable but it does not run by any other variables than int type?

Comment: Show some code or your question will be closed.

Comment: Some code is always helpful.

Comment: btw, a working example: 
`int main(){

float i = 0.0;

for(i=0.0; i<=3; i+=0.5){
printf("%.3f\n",i);

}
return 0;
}`

Comment: This post answers your question and a lot more. Did you search the SO site before asking your question? [What is the full "for" loop syntax in C (and others in case they are compatible)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276512/what-is-the-full-for-loop-syntax-in-c-and-others-in-case-they-are-compatible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop with integer variables, floating-point variables, even no variables at all.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) continue;

float f;
for(f = 0.0; f < 5; f += 0.5) continue;

for(;;) break;
```

But see [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Float-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for why you should think twice before using example 2.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to do it by using the STEP command

```
float X = 0;
//
//increase in steps of 1 x 1 thousandth
for (X = 1; X <= 100; X += 0.001) {
  // DISPLAY YOUR RESULT  maybe using: Math.Round(X, 3)
}
```

Comment: I just tried it on a web page in VB then converted it and left that line in

Comment: This question is tagged as C. Why are you using VB in your answer?