# Is the order of this C statement well defined?

Tags: c, sequence-points

The title is a bit vague as I don't really know how to define this question.

It has to do with the following code:

```
for (match         = root,
     m_matchBase   = match->requestedBase,
     m_matchLength = match->length;

     match != NULL;

     match         = match->next,
     m_matchBase   = match->requestedBase,
     m_matchLength = match->length)
{
    if (m_matchBase <= m_base && m_matchBase + m_matchLength > m_base)
        break;
    // other stuff...
}
```

Are the statements in the for loop guaranteed to run sequentially?

For example, is `m_matchBase = match->requestedBase` guaranteed to run after `match = match->next`?

Comment: Yes it's guaranteed , [further informations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54142/how-does-the-comma-operator-work)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-operator-do-in-c#52558

Comment: Is this C or C++?  Pick one.  Since you mentioned only "C" in the title, for now I'm going to assume you meant what you said, and I'll edit your tags appropriately.

Comment: i would have said 'the expressions in the for statement'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276512/what-is-the-full-for-loop-syntax-in-c-and-others-in-case-they-are-compatible

Comment: @JohnDibling, I think this applies to both C and C++, shouldn't it? These 2 languages should agree with each other on this kind of fundamental stuff I think.

Comment: @BeyondSora:  Maybe true, but clarification from OP would be nice.

Comment: Which language are you programming in? C and C++ are different languages and unless you have a specific reason you want to compare the two it is usually a bad idea to tag with both.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour, I'm aware they're different languages. However, for this particular question, I think it applies to both languages (something that C and C++ both should agree on).

Comment: Well, it is very confusing since your title specifically says *C*, so you should remove *C* from the title and make it clear you care about both cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the comma operator (which is what is being used here) will sequence the operations. This means that your loop will quite likely crash when `match->next` becomes null.

Comment: nice catch with the crash

Answer (score 5):

The *expressions* will be evaluated from left to right and there will be a *sequence point* after each evaluation. In *C* the grammar for a *for statement* without a declaration from the draft *C99* standard section `6.8.5` *Iteration statements* is:

> for ( expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ; expression<sub>opt</sub> ) statement

So the `,` in each set of expressions will be a [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) as opposed to just a separator, which means the assignments will be evaluated from left to right. This is covered in section `6.5.17` *Comma operator* which says:

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point after its evaluation. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value

Whether this is maintainable code is another question, it is important to note that when `match>next` returns `NULL` you will be invoking [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in subsequent sub-expressions. Which probably goes some way to demonstrate this is a poor choice in style since it is easy to miss and hard to check in the current form.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see c++11 standard (5.18):

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right; the left expression is a discarded-
>   value expression

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

> The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a
>   sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right
>   operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.

The `&&` operator also has a sequence point.