# How to construct a compound for loop in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, lambda

Is another `for` loop allowed in the counter section (third part) of a `for` loop? In my attempt to get elegant in writing code to produce a *right triangle*, I wrote this but it wouldn't compile:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int i, j, N = 5;
    for (i = 1;
         i <= N; 
         (for (j = 1; j <= i; j++, printf("%c", '0'));), i++)
       printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problems with your code: 1. What are the types of `i`, `j`, and `N`? 2. What is the value of `N`? 3. Where does the 3rd side get calculated?

Comment: "C/C++". There is no such language.

Comment: That construct seems to be more confusing than elegant to me.

Comment: @n.m. Metrowerks used to sell a compiler for the C/C++ language, with a pragma switching between compilation modes within a file. Although it is unlikely that the poster is using it or is even aware of it.

Comment: You could get a similar effect by putting the statements in a function and calling it.  In C++ a lambda would let you define the function in-place. I don't think this be any more readable or elegant than just writing the loops as nested `for` loops in the usual way.

Comment: To print an isolated character in each iteration is better to use `putchar()` instead of `printf("%c", ...)`.

Comment: Why is the code 'more elegant' with the body of the for loop put in the `counter` section? If you're looking for 'elegant' improvements I'd recommend replacing `printf("%c", '0')` with `printf("0")` or `putchar('0')`. `for (int i=1; i<5; ++i) { for (int j=1; j<=i; ++j) putchar('0'); putchar('\n'); }` is fine.

Comment: I don't think many people would consider a for-loop in the control section of another for-loop particularly "elegant" tbh.

Comment: Alright, you guys caught me golfing, apologies.

Comment: Pray, the SO Gods, why would anyone vote to close this one? What rule does this question break? Isn't this as original and interesting as it can get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No there are allowed only expressions or declarations.

EDIT: I am sorry. I thought you are speaking about the condition part of the loop. In the expression part of the loop there are allowed only expressions.

You could use a lambda expression that would contain this for loop. For example

```
for ( i = 1;
      i <= N;
      []( int i ) { for ( j = 1; j <= i; j++, printf("%c", '0' ) ); }( i ), i++)
```

Here is a demonstrative example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int N = 10;

    for ( int i = 1;
          i < N;
          []( int i ) 
          { 
            for ( int j = 1; j < i; j++, ( std::cout <<  '*' ) ); 
          }( i ), i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }               

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
```

Or your could define the lambda expression outside the outer loop that to make the program more readable. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int N = 10;

    auto inner_loop = []( int i ) 
    { 
        for ( int j = 1; j < i; j++, ( std::cout <<  '*' ) ); 
    };


    for ( int i = 1; i < N; inner_loop( i ), i++ )
    {
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }               

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that in general case the nested loops showed in other posts are unable to substitute the loop with the lambda-expression. For example the outer loop can contain `continue` statements that will skip the inner loop. So if you need that the inner loop will be executed in any case independing on the continue statements then this construction with the lambda expression will be helpful.:)

Comment: That's a creative use of lambdas, but I hope nobody will actually write such code...

Comment: I would have given you the vote right away, but Burr beat you to it, and I used his idea as my answer.

Comment: @Vlad Then he should just invert the loops. I'd be surprised if there exists such an algorithm that would mandate this construct.

Comment: @Mihai Todor It is not possible always to invert the loops.

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to do so. Because for loop can be easily replaced with while loop, every part of for loop can be placed in another place, where it's possible to use complex constructions. In your case, you can just change loop to the following:

```
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
        printf("%c", '0');
    }
}
```

However, if you really have to place complex action, you may use gcc extension (compound statement):

```
for (i = 1;
     i <= N; 
     ({for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) putchar('0'); }), i++) {
   printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I was looking for complex action, yes! I likes your answer since it does not use `lambdas` as the other answers do.

Comment: Did you edit on my edits? Please check the code for correctness. A final newline doesn't show up Here's the [ideone](http://ideone.com/X8kwEw) that shows this.

Comment: The third block of `for` is executed _after_ each loop. That's why `printf()` is not called last time.

Answer (score 4):

In the **counter section** of a `for()` loop, expressions are allowed, but statements are not.
And every `for()` line in C/C++ forms a new statement (it's not an expression).

However, you can nest several `for()` loops if you want.
For example, since you want a new loop in the counter sections, that means that you need to perform a loop at the end of the main `for()` loop.

This is the scheme:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < i_max; i++) {
      // stuff...


      for (int j = 0; j < j_max; j++) {
            // stuff..
      }  
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that because condition and increment parts of a `for` can only contain *expressions*. A `for` loop is an *iteration statement*, though.

Simply nest the loops like sane programers do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int N = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
             printf("0");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If you're not feeling well, though, you could use a lambda:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int N = 5;
    for (
        int i = 1;
        i <= N; 
        [=](){ for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) printf("0"); }(), printf("\n"), i++
    ) ;
}
```

Comment: C++11, if needed. But that should be a default by now.

Comment: #jrok, C++11 is not default for my g++, anyway, I didn't even know I had to compile as C++ ... that's why gcc was giving errors

Answer (score 2):

***Shortest-possible solution:***

```
main(i){for(i=1;i<11;printf("%0*d\n",i++,0));}
```

Output:

```
0
00
000
0000
00000
000000
0000000
00000000
000000000
0000000000
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/sQfCmR)

Comment: Good to know. You can actually move the `\n` into the printf statement, and make it even smaller.

Comment: This is shorter: `int N=10; for (int i=1; i<=N; printf("%0*d\n", i++, 0)) ;`

Comment: @pablo1977: how about now?

Comment: @PiotrS.: Drop the unused `j`  :)

Comment: @pablo1977: N is not needed as well though

Comment: No, it's not. Just put the constant there. And the `return` line is not mandatory in `main()` (according to standard C, I suppose the same is for C++).

Comment: @pablo1977: yes I know, but ideone complains about that

Comment: Why do you deleted the first part of your answer? Perhaps it was better than the rest, because your "shortest" version (that I upvoted) is just code-golf (and the OP asked for "elegant code"), and issues about nested `for()` loops.

Comment: This is Code Golfing in C89, a language that should be dead by now (but you can thank Microsoft for keeping it alive, though even GCC defaults to C89 mode compilations).  Such code has no place outside of Code Golf, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hat tip to [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) for the suggestion to use `lambda`. And thanks to the commentators requesting me to use `putchar()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int N;
  scanf("%d", &N);

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++, [i] {
         for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++, putchar('0'))
           ;
       }(), printf("\n"))
    ;

  return 0;
}
```

[<kbd>LIVE DEMO</kbd>](http://ideone.com/PbGIPy)

Answer (score 1):

Elegance comes with clarity.
When I want to create a string of characters, I construct a C++ object called `std::string`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  char c = '0';
  const int n = 5;

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << std::string(i, c) << '\n';
  }
}
```

So there is no need for a nested `for`-loop in this particular case. 
Otherwise put a `for`-statement in the body of the outer loop as other answers suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should avoid obfuscated code unless we get paid for making the code complex.