# Understanding Simple For Loop Code in C

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm beginner in C programming (just started) and i need help from you to understand the output of this very simple code:

```
int main()
{
   int x=1;
   for (;x<=10;x++);
   printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

output is:
11

the same output if x value is <=11
and if x value is 12 or more, it prints the exact value of x (ex: if int x=12; the output is 12).

how did the computer understand this code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the full "for" loop syntax in C (and others in case they are compatible)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276512/what-is-the-full-for-loop-syntax-in-c-and-others-in-case-they-are-compatible)

Comment: "how did the computer understand this code?" - He might have read a C book ... How about following its example?

Comment: my 2 cents... This is rarely how loops are used. The `for` loop doesn't do anything except increment `x` because of it's trailing semicolon `;`. Usually you want to wrap the body of a loop in `{...}` and actually do something in the body based on the loop control variable (`x` in this case). All this loop effectively does is insert a (quite small) time delay. In fact compiler optimizations would probably just omit the loop entirely and set `x` to 11.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers How is that a duplicate? The question you linked is about understanding obfuscated code. While this question is about asking how utterly fundamental things work.

Answer (score 3):

So,

```
int main()
{
   int x=1;           // line 1
   for (;x<=10;x++);  // line 2
   printf("%d\n",x);  // line 3
   return 0;          // line 4
}
```

Line 1 initializes x to 1.

Line 2 keeps increasing x by 1 until it reaches 11. The first semicolon indicates "don't do anything before starting the loop", `x<=10` indicates keep going until x > 10 (so when x = 11) and x++ means increase x by 1 each time. If x >= 11, this line gets basically skipped because x is already greater than 10.

Line 3 prints out x to the command line (in this case, x = 11 if x started out less than 11 or just x if x started at >= 11 due to the previous line)

Line 4 means the program was successful, exit the program.

Comment: think you should explain line 3s semi colon also

Comment: Under what circumstances does `x = 1;` make `x` start out at a value larger than 11?

Comment: It never does, however he asked why the behavior changed when x was initialized >= 11

Answer (score 0):

*for* is this:

`for(*init-expr*; *test-expr*; *update-expr*)
   *body-statement*`

Or rather, commonly, it can be decribed like this:

`*init-expr*;
 while(*test-expr*){
   *body-statement*
   *update-expr*;
 }`

and, your *for* statement is followed by a semicolon, where *body-statement* is.So, it is a "null statement", just loop and update *x*, when finishes the loop, just print the *x* after loop, so, the output is 11.