# Why does this program for checking if a line is a palindrome return a segfault?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, palindrome

I already tried Valgrind with the Valkyrie GUI and Code::Blocks, but I did not really know how to create a project to run it in the debugger, or it just did not work. The `printf("here")` lines were just for checking were the error was, however, it just sometimes returned "here4". It always returned Segmentation fault: 11, and I cannot see any line where I am adressing memory I do not own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int c, length=-1, n, m, palindrome, line[250];
int half[126];
int half2[126];
char string[250];
char charac[2];
int main(){
          while(c!=EOF){
                       c=getchar();
                       if(c=='\n' || c==EOF){ /*End of line*/
                                            /*Copies first half of line*/
                                            while(n<=length/2){
                                                              half[n]=line[n];
                                                              ++n;
                                                               }
                                            /*Copies second half of line*/
                                            for(n=0, m=length; n<=length/2; ++n, --m){
                                                                                     half2[n]=line[m]; 
                                                                                      }
                                            /*Tests if line is palindrome*/
                                            for(palindrome=1, n=0; palindrome && n<=length/2; ++n){
                                                                                                   if(half[n]!=half2[n])
                                                                                                             palindrome=0;
                                                                                                    }
                                            if(palindrome)
                                                printf("%s\nis a palindrome.\n", string);
                                            length=-1;
                                            n=0;
                                            m=0;
                                            string[0]=0;
                                            while(n<=125){
                                                         half[n]=0;
                                                         half2[n]=0;
                                                         ++n;
                                                          }
                                            n=0;
                                             }
                       else{
                           /*printf("here4");*/
                           ++length;
                           if(length>500)
                                    break; /*prevent overflow*/
                           line[length]=c;
                           sprintf(charac, "%c", c);
                           strcat(string, charac);
                            }
                        }
          return 0;
           }
```

Comment: See anything wrong with this? `for(..., n=-1; ...) { ... if (half[n]!=half2[n]) ... }`

Comment: Well, but there is a '++n' in the '...' before accessing the arrays, so it will be '0' at least.

Comment: [Nope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/276519/5522303). The increment step is run *after* the body of the loop.

Comment: Really? I thought it was the other way round. Guess I´ll just try it out.

Comment: Does not change anything, still getting segfault.

Comment: `strcpy(string, 0)` What do you think that does? Hint: Replace `0` with `NULL` (because they are equivalent) and then think about it.

Comment: It seems to work if I replace '0' or 'NULL' with '"\0"'. It just does not recognize palindromes, but that is something for a different question, I guess.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17 If you want to empty a string, you can just do `string[0] = 0;`. No need to copy anything.

Comment: @FantasyCookie17 Look at examples of loops that process arrays, they almost all start with `i = 0;`. If the increment happened first, they'd all skip the first element.

Comment: Just edited the code a bit, still returns nothing although palindromes are included in the input text.

Comment: Try separating the code reading the input from the code checking for palindromes (i.e. make a function `bool is_palindrome(const char* string)`). Your code looks too complicated for what it's trying to do

Comment: @all I corrected some things, it works now. The corrected code can be seen in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, everyone used comments instead of answers, so I am going to accept this answer in 5 minutes if nobody wants to add an own answer so the question gets closed.