# How do I start a for loop that starts at 2 but goes up to (and includes) the int variable, upperBound?

Tags: c

```
for (int i=2; i<=upperBound; i++) {
    if (num % i ==0)
        printf(""%d" is a prime number.");
}
```

I understand that I should know this stuff but I'm just starting to learn C and it's a bit confusing. I know that the condition is supposed to be in the middle, that's why I'm not sure how to include the upperbound variable.

Comment: The first line of your question is the answer to your question. The rest of your logic is wrong. For example, the first iteration of your loop will claim a number is prime if it's even.

Comment: The line `printf(""%d" is a prime number.");` does not compile, and anyway, if `num` is exactly divisible by `i` (without a remainder) then `num` *isn't* prime, and there is no point continuing with the loop.

Comment: Your algorithm is backwards. You want to stop (and return 0) if `(num % i) == 0`. Test 2 separately and then do `i += 2` so you only test _odd_ numbers. Try: `int isprime(int num) {  if ((num % 2) == 0) return 0;  for (int i = 3;  i <= upperBound;  i += 2) { if ((num % i) == 0) return 0; }  return 1; }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the full "for" loop syntax in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276512/what-is-the-full-for-loop-syntax-in-c)

Comment: The printf line should be `printf("%d is a prime number.", num);` in which the `num` variable will replace the `%d` when printing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". -- I do not understand your question in the title, as your code is the answer. Please clarify by [edit]ing your question. What is the specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop already behaves as requested.

```c
for (int i=2; i<=upperBound; i++) {
   ...
}
```

is roughly equivalent to

```c
int i=2;
while (i<=upperBound) {
   ...
   i++;
}
```

1. In the first pass of the loop, `i` is 2.
2. In the second, 3.
3. In the last pass, `i` will be equal to `upperBound`.

At the end of that pass, `i` becomes equal to `upperBound+1`, so `i<=upperBound` is no longer true, so the loop exits.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil That would be true, except `i` is scoped to the `for` loop. It doesn't equal `upperBound+1` after the loop because it doesn't exist. That is one of the differences between the two snippets. The other is how it behaves if the loop uses `continue`.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at your `while`.