How to implement one anonymous loop form like do in the evaluator as a derived expression using Scheme?
This is from SICP exercise 4.9.

Exercise 4.9.  Many languages support a variety of iteration constructs, such as do, for, while, and until. In Scheme, iterative processes can be expressed in terms of ordinary procedure calls, so special iteration constructs provide no essential gain in computational power. On the other hand, such constructs are often convenient. Design some iteration constructs, give examples of their use, and show how to implement them as derived expressions.

Example to implement do in MIT/GNU Scheme.
(define test (vector 3))
(do ((vec (make-vector 5))
      (i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ;; use assignment similar to C for loop https://stackoverflow.com/a/276519/21294350
    ;; https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/for
    ;; > cond-expression is *evaluated* before the loop body
    ((begin 
      (set! test vec)
      (= i 5)) (list vec test))
   (vector-set! vec i i))


I first tried to implement it with named-let
 (define test (vector 3))
 (let loop
   ;; > the init expressions are stored in the bindings of the variables, and then the iteration phase begins.
   ((vec (make-vector 5))
     (i 0))
   (if (begin 
          (set! test vec)
          (= i 5))
     (list vec test)
     (begin
       (vector-set! vec i i)
       ;; > the step expressions are evaluated in some *unspecified* order, the variables are bound to fresh locations, the results of the steps are stored in the bindings of the variables, and the next iteration begins.
       (loop vec (+ i 1)))))

but the above will fail if we change loop to vec.

Most of schemewiki solutions are to implement while.

Since the main problem above is name collision, so LisScheSic's 1st comment is fine to follow.
My above problem is same as woofy's and karthikk's due to introducing one new variable to body.
djrochford's (while <name> <predicate> <body>) is inappropriate as "not for do in MIT/GNU Scheme since it is anonymous" says.
jotti's (if <predicate> <body> (while <predicate> <body>)) is not "Not strictly derived expressions" as the comment says.

Solutions offered by pvk's 2nd comment



Reserve additional keywords such as while-rec

Seemingly not valid for MIT/GNU Scheme since we can even redefine primitives like +.



Implement special syntax for while as done here;

i.e. jotti's.

i.e. djrochford's



Make the interpreter scan the code for all variable names before translating

Similar to renaming




In a nut shell, "the interpreter scan the code" is possible for MIT/GNU Scheme to implement "derived expressions". "Reserve additional keywords" may work for Racket since redefinition is restricted more there.

Then I checked R5RS standard implementation (same as R7RS) (I haven't studied syntax-rules which is also not taught in SICP. I also don't know how to grasp the main ideas from the long contents in the official MIT/GNU Scheme syntax-rules doc.)
(define-syntax do
   (syntax-rules ()
     ((do ((var init step ...) ...)
         (test expr ...)
         command ...)
     (letrec
       ((loop
         (lambda (var ...)
           (if test
               (begin
                 (if #f #f)
                 expr ...)
               (begin
                 command
                 ...
                 (loop (do "step" var step ...)
                       ...))))))
       (loop init ...)))
     ((do "step" x)
     x)
     ((do "step" x y)
     y)))
;; similarly we can use named let for the above letrec part
(let loop 
 ((var init) ...)
   (if test
       ; ...... same as the above
       ))

The above actually avoids the name collision problem where loop is used by letrec above.
(do ((loop (make-vector 5))
      (i 0 (+ i 1)))
    ((= i 5) loop)
  (vector-set! loop i i))

But if I expand naively (I don't know how syntax-rules replace maybe intelligently), the error is thrown:
;; > pattern variables that occur in the template are *replaced* by the subforms they match in the input.
(letrec
  ((loop
    (lambda (loop i)
      (if (= i 5)
          (begin
            (if #f #f)
            loop)
          (begin
            (vector-set! loop i i)
            (loop loop (+ i 1)))))))
  (loop (make-vector 5) 0))
;The object #(0 #f #f #f #f) is not applicable.



Q:
As the above shows, the main problem is "name collision". "In a nut shell" works possibly and define-syntax works although I don't know how that does internally. How does define-syntax work to solve the above loop name collision? If that is complex, is there some more elegant way to implement do using "derived expressions" besides scan and "Reserve additional keywords"?
p.s.

the only former exercise in chapter 4 related with iteration exercise 4.8 to implement named-let let name ((variable init) …) expr expr … doesn't have the above problem since name and variables are implicitly contained in exprs. So there is no "name collision" otherwise the definition is wrong. Then we can use Z-combinator to avoid "name collision" between inits and name as LisScheSic's 1st comment does.

Thanks for Shawn's help. We can add one (bkpt "test loop") before (loop (do "step" var step ...) ...). Then when running do after (define-syntax do ......) by scheme --interactive --eval '(load "demo.scm")' (I used MIT/GNU Scheme):
2 bkpt> (debug)
...
Expression (from stack):
    (begin <!> (.loop.0 loop (+ i 1)))
 subproblem being executed (marked by <!>):
    (bkpt "test loop")

As the above shows, here the loop in syntax-rules is renamed to .loop.0 (if we use .loop.0 as one variable in the code, then the interpreter will still rename loop to .loop.0. But the code can still run. Maybe as the link offered by Shawn says "They are paired up properly", so the interpreter won't mess up the superficial name collision of .loop.0).



2.1
As this comment says, the name collision may be actually avoided by

Maybe that is done by just keeping duplicate vars instead of substituting that with loop or i in template (so avoid loop collision) and the clever pairing mechanism (so no name collision due to duplicate var names).

implied by Shawn's link example in the context of "name collisions":

Since we run the expansion step three times, one for each variable to be assigned, we get three variables named temp.  They are paired up properly because we generated all references to them at the same time.

So probably at each expansion step, var will be also paired up with the appropriate variable like loop or i at the expansion step when applying (do ((loop (make-vector 5)) ...)). (loop (do "step" var step ...) ...) will be paired with the definition of the loop func in letrec instead of the variable loop vector probably at the define-syntax step.



Later when reading one QA about cons-stream syntax implementation, I found one comment referring to define-macro which is said many times in 6.001 lec's and rec's. So I searched a bit  with 'lisp "define-macro"' or 'common lisp "define-macro"' used in reference link of this Reddit post. Then I found this QA and then searched "scheme syntax-case". From Guile (one Scheme dialect) doc about syntax-case, I checked Guile doc about define-macro saying the name conflict problem for that.
The search path is a bit zigzag...

3.1. How syntax-rules works including avoiding name conflict:

"Hygiene"
Then I checked the Guile doc for syntax-rules due to hints from the context of my-or in syntax-case doc. "Hygiene" part says well about how the above possible name conflict is avoided.

syntax-rules macros have a magical property: they preserve referential transparency. When you read a macro definition, any free bindings in that macro are resolved relative to the macro definition; and when you read a macro instantiation, all free bindings in that expression are resolved relative to the expression.
This property is sometimes known as hygiene, and it does aid in code cleanliness.


The above means same as "lexical scoping" said in wikipedia Hygienic macro which is same as what SICP section 3.2 says about procedure that procedure application uses the env when procedure is defined/created instead of that when applied.

identify free variables in the macro definition and make sure those names are looked up in the scope of the macro definition instead of the scope where the macro was used.

IMHO this is also implied in Guile syntax-rules definition shown in Guile syntax-case doc which returns one syntax object "carrying with it all relevant metadata from the source expression, such as lexical identity and source location". That metadata may be similar to procedure env created when defined (i.e. "macro definition" scope or lexical identity here where identity means character IMHO).

For the above "loop" example, the conflicts are between local bindings of macro definition and macro instantiation. (let ((t #t)) (my-or #f t)) in the doc is one example for local bindings of macro definition and free bindings of macro instantiation. IMHO free bindings of macro definition is normally used in one nested situation like head-symbol used in the inner syntax for this Guile  example.



3.1.1. referential transparency
The wikipedia referential transparency is also said in wikipedia Hygienic macro (IMHO the  definition in the context of "semantic equivalence" is just saying attention is needed for semantic equivalence, but not saying the definition of referential transparency)

Each expression built from a referentially opaque linguistic construction states something about a subexpression, whereas each expression built from a referentially transparent linguistic construction states something not about a subexpression, meaning that the subexpressions are ‘transparent’ to the expression, acting merely as ‘references’ to something else.

This is similar to this QA answer definition and also rewrite system said in wikipedia referential transparency

the only thing we need to know about the sub-expression is its value.


The QA answer definition implies the following implementation ideas from Guile syntax-case doc which is similar to tagged data taught in SICP.

represents identifiers as annotated syntax objects, attaching such information to those syntax objects as is needed to maintain referential transparency


So the above do can be seen as one "referentially transparent linguistic construction" where we don't care about what var init step etc are internally (so they are ‘transparent’ for do) and they are just ‘references’ implied by pattern language.


3.1.2 Why syntax-case is introduced? This is explained well in Guile doc "Why syntax-case?".

use guard with identifier? etc.

datum->syntax to gets "the lexical context of the output expression" possibly, i.e. (let ((it test)) ...) in aif example there. Then use syntax-case wrapper to do pattern substitution for it.
We can also use with-syntax syntactic sugar.

This aif example is almost same as this sc-macro-transformer example. But the latter uses free-names to exclude searching it in the syntactic environment which can be extended by define-syntax etc (i.e. "the environment of lexical variable" in syntax-case doc IMHO) while syntax-case can explicitly "introduce bindings into the lexical context of the output expression", so it is less fine-grained IMHO.


#, etc which is also used for define-macro as the above comment shows.





3.2 After the above understanding, I found the contents related with name conflict from the a bit long contents in the above MIT/GNU Scheme doc link



If a literal identifier is inserted as a bound identifier then it is in effect renamed to prevent inadvertent captures of free identifiers.
(let ((=> #f))
  (cond (#t => 'ok)))           ⇒ ok


Here "literal" => is implied in (cond (test => result)) part in cond definition in R7RS (this is said in R7RS but not the above MIT/GNU Scheme doc link. Anyway MIT/GNU Scheme offers 2 links including R7RS for syntax-rules, I should check all links offered by MIT/GNU Scheme doc next time). "bound identifier" means ((=> #f)) in let here. Here "inadvertent captures of free identifiers" means => in literals part of (syntax-rules (else =>) ...) and "local" means same as "bound".

The macro transformer for cond recognizes => as a local variable, and hence an expression, and not as the top-level identifier =>, which the macro transformer treats as a syntactic keyword.


IMHO here "syntactic keyword" is a bit inappropriate since => is not one transformer but one literal in cond transformer.
Anyway if we use merely (cond (#t => 'ok)), then it recognizes => as free so just one symbol/identifier.



macros part doc also says the above one with less distraction. Just search "shadow". This also says cond definition is from R4RS.



An instance of syntax-rules produces a new macro transformer by specifying a sequence of hygienic rewrite rules.

This is not readable for newbies like me. The above macros doc also says the relation among "hygienic", "referentially transparent" and "lexical scoping" but with less explanation. So after all, Guile doc is much better to read at least for newbies.



3.3 the definition of macro transformer including syntax-rules

The above macros link says

The set of rules that specifies how a use of a macro is transcribed into a more primitive expression is called the transformer of the macro.

This says the transformer uses rules to transcribe. But this  doesn't convey much information.

As Guile "Defining Macros" doc implies, we should visit the Guile "Syntax-rules Macros" and "Support for the syntax-case System" docs for transformer definition.
IMHO the definition by syntax-case is more readable and understandable, and syntax-rules implementation by syntax-case is also more understandable.

"Further Information" in the former recommends reading R7RS which is almost same as the above MIT/GNU Scheme doc link but with helpful references. It also refers to "Joe Marshall’s syntax-rules Primer for the Merely Eccentric." (IMHO this pdf is more readable) link offered by Shawn. It also recommends reading syntax-case implicitly.

The latter gives one more helpful definition for transformer with procedure (IMHO this is better)

So the lambda wrapper is simply a leaky implementation detail, that syntax transformers are just functions that transform syntax to syntax. ... syntax-case is simply a way to take apart and put together program text, and to be a valid syntax transformer it needs to be wrapped in a procedure. ... However a syntax transformer procedure must return a syntax object, so most uses of syntax-case do end up returning syntax objects.

It also shows why syntax is needed to avoid name conflict where "raw Scheme forms" seems to just the naive replacement procedure (i.e. my original naive thoughts about syntax-rules) by the demo there.

Unlike traditional Lisp macros (see Lisp-style Macro Definitions), syntax-case macros transform syntax objects, not raw Scheme forms.


"syntax" definition: Here lexical context/identity and "scope annotations" may all mean lexical scoping information which may be probably similar to environment taught in SICP section 3.2 (this is also implied in "lexical contour").

Create a syntax object wrapping form within the current lexical context.
The interesting thing about this is that within a syntax expression, any appearance of a pattern variable is substituted into the resulting syntax object, carrying with it all relevant metadata from the source expression, such as lexical identity and source location.
The source and scope annotations attached to the syntax object are of interest to how the macro expander computes the result


Same as SICP 4.1 implementation where env is shown as '<procedure-env>, guile automatically shows #<syntax foo> for syntax object. read-syntax etc doesn't allow checking inside syntax.










I found Name collision, Name conflict, Captured Variable and variable shadowing are used interchangeably implied by their definitions and this answer. That may make reading the long doc a bit inconvenient since we don't which of these 3 that doc uses. For example, the above MIT/GNU Scheme syntax-rules doc uses "capture" which makes my original search for that long doc by "collision" fail.


All in all, next time we need to check some Scheme implementation details, IMHO we can check Guile (one Scheme dialect) doc first since it is more helpful and it also refers to the guide offered by Shawn in syntax-rules doc. Then we can check MIT/GNU Scheme doc including R7RS or SRFI links. But anyway MIT/GNU Scheme doc is one good starting place to check MIT/GNU Scheme procedure APIs.

https://hipster.home.xs4all.nl/lib/scheme/gauche/define-syntax-primer.txt is good reading.

But basically the loop in the macro definition and the loop used by the caller of the macro are two different variables despite having the same name. The macro expander keeps track of which is which and won't mix them up. There's probably an existing q&a about it that this would be a duplicate of...

I haven't studied syntax-rules which is also not taught in SICP. To be fair, I don't think syntax macros had been invented yet when SICP was written. One of the times its use of a minimal subset of scheme instead of all the language paid off by not introducing by now long obsolete macro systems.

@Shawn That link is helpful although much longer than the official doc. I didn't look through that doc detailedly. By searching "collision", I found gen-temps-and-sets is very helpful. Then "The answer lies in this template: ..." version gen-temps-and-sets shows how Scheme manipulates "name collision" when expanding by "It will be a different syntactic object than any created during any other expansion step". So for (multiple-value-set! (a b c) (values 1 2 3)), similarly duplicate variables will be also bound to a, b, c at each step.

Then for the above example, vars will be bound to loop, i consecutively. So var is  implicitly "paired up properly" with the loop vector instead of the loop in template. The link doesn't say further how Scheme avoids the messing name collision caused by either argument in the above example or expansion (maybe still others) detailedly in implementation. Maybe some clever techniques...

"keeps track of which is which and won't mix them up." may mean "They are paired up
properly because we generated all references to them at the same time." (i.e. the pair elements are got at the same expansion stage, so they can be paired) in the link.

"I don't think syntax macros had been invented yet when SICP was written.": Do you think it is fine to use the above define-syntax ...  as the solution to exercise-4.9 since IMHO this is the only one solution I found up to now solving with the above name collision problem? Maybe that is done by just keeping duplicate vars instead of substituting that with loop or i in template (so avoid loop collision) and the clever pairing mechanism (so no name collision due to duplicate var names).

https://www.reddit.com/r/scheme/comments/5q5nag/comment/dcx3c4v/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button (This is got when googling "gauche scheme Syntax-rules Primer" to get some possible summary of your offered link although this link  doesn't refer to your offered link) recommends "syntactic closures", i.e. IMHO lambda in Scheme.

This may mean we can finish exercise-4.9 using only lambda probably based on  combinator like the powerful Z combinator used in http://community.schemewiki.org/?sicp-ex-4.8. @Shawn Do you have any thoughts about using lambda calculus or combinatory logic to finish exercise-4.9?

The SICP question is about adding new derived forms to the interpreter being developed in that chapter, so presumably anything you do for it would use the techniques already gone over in the book. Shouldn't require anything too fancy or exotic. Definitely shouldn't require macros

@Shawn Yes. The book https://mitp-content-server.mit.edu/books/content/sectbyfn/books_pres_0/6515/sicp.zip/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html says "a procedure cond->if that transforms cond expressions into if expressions" and "Expressions (such as cond) that we choose to implement as syntactic transformations are called derived expressions". Then IMHO this is same as what R7RS says "definitions for the derived expression types in terms of the primitive expression types" in section 7.3 p68.

So the template offered by R7RS above is actually "derived expression" but name collision is implicitly manipulated by syntax-rules. Do you know some ingenious tricks to solve with the above name collision problem without using macro? If not, IMHO the above template can be exercise-4.9 solution, is that right?
