"Variable reference to a syntactic keyword" when using syntax-rules
minimal working code demo:
(define (demo-tree)
  (custom-cons 0 1))
(define-syntax custom-cons
  (syntax-rules ()
    (
    ;  (_ x y)
     (custom-cons x y)
     (cons-stream x y)
     )))
(custom-cons 0 1)
(demo-tree)
(custom-cons 0 1)

Here only (demo-tree) will fail with error ";Variable reference to a syntactic keyword: custom-cons" but other lambda body's are run well.

This problem is also shown in this QA How is the sicp cons-stream implemented?. But that QA codes work fine for me and OP ignored that problem later.
This solution for the same problem above is related with compiling. This is different from the above.
Q:
How to make the above syntax custom-cons work in procedure?

When demo-tree was compiled, custom-cons was unknown, so it was assumed to be a variable. The macro needs to be defined before it's used, otherwise it can't transform the syntax.

@molbdnilo Thanks. So this is where define-syntax and define differ. Maybe syntactic environment https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref/Syntactic-Binding-Constructs.html needs to be used differently from environment. The latter is taught in SICP while the former won't as Shawn https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79098453/how-to-implement-one-anonymous-loop-form-like-do-in-the-evaluator-as-a-derived-e#comment139473850_79098453 "I don't think syntax macros had been invented yet when SICP was written" implies.

I don't think it's as much about not having been invented as it is about them having no relevance to the points that SICP is trying to make; it is a book about computer programs, not a book about Scheme specifically.
